# How to render Ext.js tab panel to html div element

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am trying to render Ext.js tab panel to html div element.

```
tabpanel=Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
                renderTo:,
                items:[...]
}
```

My div element:

```
  <div id="popup-content"></div>
```

In the place of renderTo property I tried with :

```
document.getElementById('popup-content')
Ext.getElementById('popup-content')
```

I even try to put only id tag *'popup-content'*

Every time tab panel is rendered but it loses its functionality so I  can't switch between tabs. When i try to render my tab with value of renderTo property set as:

```
Ext.getBody()
```

It works fine. 
Any ides how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like it works: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nqb
Is there anything in console?

Comment: @beso9595 I have tried with you code also but it won't work, there is no  output from console. I can't figure out where is the problem :\ , this is how my tab looks like but it isn't working inside popup https://ibb.co/gyvBUf

Comment: I think the problem is with rendering element inside map canvas, don't know why but I also don't know how to overcome it..

Comment: Link your fiddle again, post got deleted